# Access data from multiple layouts within a Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have question concerning fragments but let me give you a bit of context so my question is slightly more understandable.

I have this app with two tabs. One is a ADD tab where you fill in info like name, address etc. Then this data is put into a listview_item and this listview_item gets put into a listview on the List tab.

Now I use a fragments instead of an activity. However I do not know how to access the Xml layout file from the list fragment within the add fragment so I can populate the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer the question I have to ask: Is this really what you want? The Fragment where you put the data from the ADD tab is empty as long as the user didn't put any data into it and it will look weird. Maybe a different design approach is better for your usecase.

If your really want this I can think of this solution:

In your Activity you add a Method like this one:

```
public void addDataToOtherFragment(YourData data){
    OtherFragment fragment = (OtherFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("your_tag"); //Or keep a reference to your Fragment

    fragment.addData(data);
}
```

Then you call that Method from your Fragment like this:

```
MyActivity activity = ((MyActivity) activity) getActivity();

activity.addDataToOtherFragment(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put a method like `void addData(Data data)` in your activity (where Data is the actual type of data you want to add. In this method you put the code for populating the list view fragment with the added data.

Then in your add fragment you call `YourActivity activity = (YourActivity) getActivity()` and `activity.add(yourData)` whenever you want to add data to the list fragment.